# How to replace variable names in external js files

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am working on a node.js Terminal project that needs to compile javascript files for the anti-data leak before running!

Does anyone know of an easy way of doing something like below with node.js and the files once compiled will be running in an electron browser page!

Before compiled:

```
var text = "Hello my friends";
var num = 123;
function test(abc) {
  let num = 3;
  let comp = abc + 3;
  return comp;
}
```

After compiled:

```
window.saves[project name here].text = "Hello my friends";
window.saves[project name here].num = 123;
window.saves[project name here].test = function(abc) {
  let num = 3;
  let comp = abc + 3;
  return comp;
}
```

Feel free to ask questions and I'll try my best to answer them to help you help me.

Comment: If you can count on the code being indented properly, a simple regular expression would suffice. That said, it would probably be better in the long-run to use something designed for this sort of compartmentalization, such as Webpack (works for browsers, not sure about Electron)

Comment: ill look into webpack compiling scripts midrun thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using [Babel plugins](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/plugins).

[Babel](https://babeljs.io/) is a javascript transpiler that can perform code transformations and has an API that can be easily used in node, but writing a plugin for it is not a trivial task.

I found this article to be a good starting point: [Babel Plugin Handbook](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/plugin-handbook.md)
Also an aditional article here: [Understanding ASTs by Building Your Own Babel Plugin](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-asts-building-babel-plugin/)

There are also some plugins out there which are not quite what you're looking for, but fairly similar. Perpahs you can inspect their source code to see how they're implemented:

- [babel-plugin-inline-replace-variables](https://github.com/wssgcg1213/babel-plugin-inline-replace-variables)
- [babel-plugin-undeclared-variables-check](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-undeclared-variables-check)
- [babel-plugin-transform-global-system-wrapper](https://github.com/systemjs/babel-plugin-transform-global-system-wrapper)